# SQL SUM to ignore NULL value

Tags: sql, sum

I have a table TEST_TABLE as follows:

```
Name     x_col       y_col
=======================
Jay     NULL     2
```

This is a simplistic representation of a much larger issue but will suffice.

When I do the following query I get `NULL` returned

```
SELECT SUM(x_col + y_col) FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE Name='Jay'
```

I want it to be `2`. I thought the `SUM()` method ignores NULL values. How can I ignore values that are null in this query? Or actually in general, as this is a problem for a lot of my algorithms.

Comment: `sum(coalesce(x_col, 0) + coalesce(y_col, 0))`?

Comment: @arsenal88 . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  However, your question regards standard SQL so the database doesn't actually matter.

Answer (score 4):

You get `NULL` because `NULL + 2` returns `NULL`.  The `SUM()` has only one row, and if the `+` expression is `NULL`, then the `SUM()` returns `NULL`.

If you want `NULL` to be treated as `0`, the use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(x_col, 0) + COALESCE(y_col, 0))
FROM TEST_TABLE
WHERE Name = 'Jay';
```

One final note.  If you start with your data and filtered out *all* rows, then the result will still be NULL.  To get `0`, you need an additional `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(COALESCE(x_col, 0) + COALESCE(y_col, 0)), 0)
FROM TEST_TABLE
WHERE Name = 'Jayden';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use COALESCE to replace NULL with 0.

```
SELECT sum(coalesce(x_col, 0) + coalesce(y_col, 0)) FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE Name='Jay'
```